# any idea why im not getting the correct answer in this simple script?

Tags: python

trying to do a simple addition in first function and then a multiplication. Why iam i getting 16 instead of 24 as the answer ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

nums = [1,2,3,4]

def add():

    for i in nums :
        x = i+i
    return x


def multiple():

    for i in nums :
        y = i*i
    return y

print add()
print multiple()
```

Comment: You should probably by doing `x += i+i` and `y += i*i`. Also how do you think this should work?

Comment: You're printing two values. Which one is incorrect? Please be specific when asking questions.

Comment: Replace  `x = i+i` with `x+=i` and  `y = i*i` with `y *= i`.

Comment: x += i+i gives an error saying x reference before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code doesn't work correctly because you are only returning the result of the last element in the list

simplest implementation without sum():

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]

def add():
    x = 0
    for i in nums :
        x += i
    return x


def multiple():
    y = 1
    for i in nums :
        y *= i
    return y

print add()
print multiple()
```

note you don't need to use index you can simply iterate the numbers in both

notice that x and y need to be initalized (and for addition its 0 and multiplication its 1)

Comment: because the identity of multiplication is 1 i.e. if you start with 0 multiplication by zero is always zero

Answer (score 4):

You only add/multiply the last line

So is X=4*4 = 16 for mulitply and
X=4+4 = 8 for add

the previous attempts are overwritten in the for-loop

Comment: Add `x = 0` before `for i in nums :` and the write `x += i` instead of `x = i + i`

Answer (score 2):

You replace the value each time in the loop, so the output is only the result of the last iteration: 4*4.

Not exactly what calculation you want to do that will give you 24, but maybe you want to add the result to the previous value of y, or multiple it?

Comment: sorry, should have been clearer. add should add up all values in list and that works fine. multiply should multiple each value by one another so should give 24 but its giving me 16

Comment: But that's not what your code does at all; it multiplies each value by *itself*, and only stores the last result.

Answer (score 2):

**Here you go:**

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]

def add():
    return sum(nums)


def multiple():
    result = 1
    for num in nums:
        result *= num
    return result

print add()
print multiple()
```

**Output:**

```
10
24
```

> If you don't want to use **`sum`** built-in function then you can use this function:

```
def add():
    sum_result = 0
    for num in nums:
        sum_result += num
    return sum_result
```

Comment: Maybe little explanation about `for` loop, `sum()` and `range`? Also, `xrange()` is recommended in Python 2.x.

Comment: Indeed, though it works, which is great, it does not really answer the question, which was why his code does not work in the first place. (I admit I'm nitpicking)

Comment: can you explan this line please   for i in range(0, len(nums)):

Comment: @johndoe12345 I've updated my answer. Just use `for num in nums` which iterates over each item (number) in `nums` list and in every iteration a number will be assigned to `num` (starting from the first one)

Comment: yes ok but can you explain that line anyway as i would like to understand it     for i in range(0, len(nums))

Answer (score -1):

x = i+i will get executed for each of the values and the print the last one...

so will print 8 for the add and 16 for multiplication.